# in Torchaudio=0.7.0, where is torchaudio.functional.istft?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I used `torchaudio.functional.isftf` when the version torchaudio=0.4.0

But now, the version of torchaudio has been upgraded to 0.7.0, so I installed it, but `torchaudio.functional.istft` is gone.

I need to learn a deep learning model using `torchaudio.functional.istft`.  How do I do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's deprecated now in favor of [`torch.istft`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.istft.html#torch.istft).

Check [release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/releases) and [PR#523](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/pull/523).